# IPV6 address shortening in shell and powershell

Tags: shell, powershell

I have to make a script in shell and PowerShell that shortens ipv6 addresses as much as possible.

Like:

```
Input: 2001:0db8:03cd:0000:0000:ef45:0006:0123
Output: 2001:db8:3cd:::ef45:6:123
```

And the script should give a description of itself if -help parameter used but i dont know how to do that in PowerShell.

This is my code in PowerShell, it shortens the addresses correctly:

```
    param([parameter(Mandatory=$true)]$file)

if (test-path $file){
    foreach ($ip in Get-Content $file){
        $ip=$ip.Replace("0000","")
        Write-Host $ip

}
}
```

I have no idea how to do the shortening in shell, I tried like this but didn't work:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $1 = "-help" ]
then
echo description

else file = $1
fi

for ip in `cat ipv6.txt`
do
    $ip=$line
    $replace=""
    $echo ${var//0000/$replace}
done
```

This is the txt file with the addresses:
http://uptobox.com/6woujdvdfkmh

Comment: I'm suspicious that a triple colon is not a correct shortening. `03cd:0000:0000:ef` would become `3cd::ef`, wouldn't it? And your code would wrongly shorten an address with two separate sets of four-zeros (`2001:0db8:0000:0000:004f:0000:0000:0123`), because a double colon can only appear once in a shortened address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We might be going to the same school. This is what I was told to do and it works perfectly:

```
cat filename | sed -e 's/:0*/:/g' filename
```

Comment: That's wrong though. It would shorten `:0000:0000:0000:` to `::::`, which is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

The beauty of PowerShell is that you have access to a rich library that has methods for doing this for you.  Try this:

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Converts long form IP address into its short form
.DESCRIPTION
    Converts long form IP address into its short form
.PARAMETER IPAddress
    The IP address to convert.
.EXAMPLE
    PS C:\> ConvertTo-IPAddressCompressedForm 2001:0db8:03cd:0000:0000:ef45:0006:0123
#>
function ConvertTo-IPAddressCompressedForm($IPAddress) {
     [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse($IPAddress).IPAddressToString
}

C:\> ConvertTo-IPAddressCompressedForm 2001:0db8:03cd:0000:0000:ef45:0006:0123
2001:db8:3cd::ef45:6:123
```

Note that to get usage in PowerShell based on the doc comments use:

```
ConvertTo-IPAddressCompressedForm -?
```

Comment: Thank you this works, but I have to do this in shell too somehow.

Comment: Which shell?  You tagged your question with PowerShell, you can do the above in PowerShell, as I have shown.  Can you clarify what you mean by `have to do this in shell too`?

Comment: Oh I see. I was thinking that the `shell` tag was just a generic reference to shells.  But you want this to work in UNIX sh - not csh, korn shell or Bash but sh.  Perhaps someone familiar with sh can answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$longIPAddress = '2001:0db8:03cd:0000:0000:ef45:0006:0123'
$shortIPAddress = ([IPAddress]$longIPAddress).IPAddressToString
$shortIPAddress
2001:db8:3cd::ef45:6:123
```